# Can someone explain in layman terms how the Contrastive Divergence algorithm works step by step?

Tags: machine-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I am interested in learning about Restricted Boltzmann Machines (RBMs), but I have trouble understanding how an RBM is trained using contrastive divergence. There are only few papers on this topic and most of them require knowing advanced probabilistic stuff that are beyond my capability at this point.

Can someone explain the algorithm step by step in layman terms using pseudocode? without going into details about Markov chains and stuff.